# How do I pass multiple model IDs into comments add action in CakePHP?

Tags: cakephp, model, controller

My question concerns how I can use one comments controller with multiple 'belongs to' controllers.

I want to add comments to news, posts, and matches (it's a tennis website). I've got the comments add action setup to use the 'ajax' helper and I'm also using `counterCache` to keep track of the number of comments for each news, post and match.

What I don't know, is how to pass in the unique ID (news, posts, matches) into the comments controller add action so the form saves the comment and news_id, post_id or match_id, 
whichever is passed in the form.

What I'm thinking is if the form is setup to collect the unique ID in such a way that what gets passed is specific to that controller (news,post,match). The result would be that the add action adds the comment along with the news/post/match ID value.

Otherwise I'd have to setup a post_comments, news_comments and match_comments controller to handle each, and that wouldn't be the [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) approach I'm after.

I'm still building my knowledge and understanding of [CakePHP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CakePHP). How can I achive what I have set out to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your comment database table should look like this:

```
id | belongs_to | foreign_id | ....
-------------------------------------
   |            |            |
```

`belongs_to` is either `enum` or `varchar`

Then in your model you can associate the comment model like this
in the comment model:

```
var $belongsTo = array(
  'News' => array(
    'className' => 'News',
    'foreignKey' => 'foreign_id',
    'conditions' => array('Comment.belongs_to'=>'News'),
    'fields' => '',
    'order' => ''
  ),
  'Post' => array(
    'className' => 'Post',
    'foreignKey' => 'foreign_id',
    'conditions' => array('Comment.belongs_to'=>'Post'),
    'fields' => '',
    'order' => ''
  )
);
```

And in the Post-Model:

```
var $hasMany = array(
  'Comment' => array(
    'className' => 'Comment',
    'foreignKey' => 'foreign_id',
    'dependent' => true,
    'conditions' => array('Comment.belongs_to' => 'Post'),
    'fields' => '',
    'order' => 'Comment.created DESC',
    'limit' => '',
    'offset' => '',
    'exclusive' => '',
    'finderQuery' => '',
    'counterQuery' => ''
  )
);
```

Comment: Thank you. This approach has worked very well, it's also helped me expand my architectural approach to cakePHP and relationships between models.

Much appreciated, Paul